# How to know what versions of Django are supported by a particular Wagtail release?

Tags: wagtail

I fear I've missed it, but I can't seem to find a spot in the docs that specifically lays out what version(s) of Django are tested to work. I did notice the requirements.txt file. Should that be my guide then? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The definitive source of information about supported Django versions is [setup.py](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/setup.py) in the Wagtail codebase. The [release notes](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.8.1/releases/index.html) section of the documentation will tell you when a new version is supported, or an old version is dropped, but there's currently no place in the documentation that will tell you the supported Django versions for a given Wagtail release. ([There probably should be!](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/2429))

The requirements.txt in the project template won't tell you the full range of supported versions - usually it points to the latest compatible major Django release, as that's the one you're encouraged to use on new projects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! As of this writing you can find them here: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0.1/releases/upgrading.html

I had the same question today and thanks to @gasman who lead me to the right place where I should be digging.